# How to generate access="field.camelcase-underscore" with Nhibernate's mapping by code?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I can't seem to find a way to set the naming strategy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mapper.Class<YourClass>(cm => cm.Property(x => x.YourProperty,
                                          pm => pm.Access(Accessor.Field)));
```

Comment: Sure, but how do you manipulate the naming strategy: mcamelcase-underscore, camelcase-underscore etc as in field.someStrategyName?

Comment: you don't have to: it's automatically detected.